# Prove that: $\tan (2\tan^{-1} (x))=2\tan (\tan^{-1} (x)+\tan^{-1} (x^3))$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Prove that: $\tan (2\tan^{-1} (x))=2\tan (\tan^{-1} (x)+\tan^{-1} (x^3))$

My Attempt'
Let $\tan^{-1} (x)=A$
$$x=\tan (A)$$
Now,
L.H.S.$=\tan (2\tan^{-1} (x))$
$$=\tan (2A)$$
$$=\dfrac {2\tan (A)}{1-\tan^2 (A)}$$
$$=\dfrac {2x}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is good, indeed from

$$\tan (A+B) = \frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1- \tan A \tan B} $$

for RHS we obtain

$$2\tan (\tan^{-1} (x)+\tan^{-1} (x^3))=2\frac{x+x^3}{1- x^4}=\frac{2x(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}=\frac{2x}{1- x^2}=LHS$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}2\tan (\tan^{-1} (x)+\tan^{-1} (x^3)) =&2\tan \left(\tan^{-1}  \dfrac{x + x^3}{1 - x^4}\right) \\= \ & 2\left(  \dfrac{x + x^3}{1 - x^4}\right) = 2\left(  \dfrac{x }{1 - x^2}\right) \\= \ & \dfrac{2\tan(\tan^{-1} x)}{1 - \tan^2 (\tan^{-1} x)} = \tan(2 \tan^{-1}x) \end{align}$$